# JS process input after delay only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, delay

I want to listen input field and run processing input value to output value after 3 seconds after finnishing of inputting value.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input').on('input', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log('Triggered input: ' + value);

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Changing output to: ' + value);
            $('.output').text(value); // example operation
        }, 3000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" class="input" />
<hr>
<div class="output">...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But the code above will process every single character, instead of expected full string.

In the other words. I want to type "abc", and this value should be processed only one time after delay as "abc", instead of, as now as, as "a", then "ab", then "abc".

How to fix that?

Comment: It's because the `input` event fires on every keypress.  You need to *debounce* the timeout (which the second part of the accepted answer shows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the code above will process every single character, instead of expected full string.

That's because you're using the `value` variable, whose value you set when *scheduling* the function. If you want the value as of when the function runs, wait and get it then:

```
$('.input').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        var value = input.val();
        console.log('Changing output to: ' + value);
        $('.output').text(value); // example operation
    }, 3000);
});
```

Now the function will use the value of the input as of when the function runs. But there's another problem: If you get multiple events within the three seconds, you'll get multiple calls. You probably want to cancel earlier calls to that function if you get another `input` event before the function fires? E.g.:

```
$('.input').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);

    // Cancel any outstanding call (no-op if it's already happened)
    var handle = input.data("handle");
    if (handle) {
        clearTimeout(handle);
    }

    // Schedule the new one
    handle = setTimeout(function() {
        var value = input.val();
        console.log('Changing output to: ' + value);
        $('.output').text(value); // example operation
        // Since we've fired, clear the handle
        input.data("handle", 0);
    }, 3000);

    // Remember that handle on the element
    input.data("handle", handle");
});
```